# Cliqset.com Error 403 while trying to update any data through API

Tags: api

I used both Fiddler and my test C# application to update my profile information in Cliqset.com through their API but I always get 403 error. It works well when I just want to get my profile info, not to update. I use all necessary HTTP headers, like CliqsetConsumerKey and Authorization.
Thank you.
When I try to get my status, I use this:

```
GET https://api.cliqset.com/user/cosmorocket/status HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Y**********rZXQ6ZnVsY3J1bTA=
CliqsetConsumerKey: 11**********3c2ccd26c4ca946e3d8e
Host: api.cliqset.com
```

And it returns this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2009 05:17:37 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA     date=200807181417)/JBossWeb-2.0
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 153
Set-Cookie: csp=appInst2; path=/
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><StatusEntry><Updated>2009-06-09T18:09:29.315Z</Updated><Status>cliqsetting all day long</Status></StatusEntry>
```

But if I use the same credentials for updating with this request:

```
PUT https://api.cliqset.com/200905/user/cosmorocket/status HTTP/1.1
```

I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2009 05:25:04 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 9
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Error 403
```

Comment: I suggest you include with your post some info from the Fiddler log, i.e.
- the exact url you are calling
- the raw contents of the http call

Feel free to blank out any private info, but raw data is everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted tech support and solved the problem. Each time a new user uses my registered application it's necessary to make an authenticated GET
request to 'https://api.cliqset.com/200905/user/useridentifier'. Notice that you don't change 'useridentifier' to any other login name, just leave it as it is. This
will setup the appropriate permissions to update data.
I did this request and now it works well.